# How to hide the dropdown when clicked outside the container

Tags: javascript, css

I have a International country code selector code for my website but the problem I'm facing is that I want to hide the dropdown menu when anyone clicks outside the container, I have already written the code for this feature but the bug I'm facing right now is that It closes the dropdown menu when anyone clicks inside of the container, not the outside. it's doing the exact opposite.

I want to hide the menu when clicked outside.

Please check out my Highlighted code -

```js
  // Cache the elements
  const xbutton = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .telcode');
  const container = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .container');
  const input = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector input');
  const list = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .list');
  
  // Add event listeners to the button, input, and list
  // We use a process called "event delegation" on the list
  // to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM
  // https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/
  xbutton.addEventListener('click', handleButton);
  input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  list.addEventListener('click', handleListClick);
  document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
  
  // Handles the document click - it checks to see if the clicked
  // part of the document has a parent element which is either
  // `null` or is the HTML element, and then closes the container
  // if it's open
  function handleDocumentClick(e) {
    const { parentElement } = e.target;
  }


/************************************************************************/
/****************** Hide the menu when clicked outside ******************/
/************************************************************************/
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (container.contains(event.target)) {
    if (container.classList.contains('show')) {
      container.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
});
/************************************************************************/
/****************** Hide the menu when clicked outside ******************/
/************************************************************************/


  
  // All of the data held as objects within an array
  const data = [
    { name: 'Afganistan', code: '69', flag: 'afg' },
    { name: 'Barbados', code: '1-246', flag: 'brb' },
    { name: 'Bolivia', code: '591', flag: 'bol' },
    { name: 'Cuba', code: '53', flag: 'cub' },
    { name: 'Fiji', code: '679', flag: 'fji' },
  ];
  
  // Filters the data based on the characters
  // at the start of the provided name
  function filterData(data, value) {
    return data.filter(obj => {
      return (
        obj.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
        || obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
  }
  
  // Create a series of list items based on the
  // data passed to it
  function createListHtml(data) {
    return data.map(obj => {
      const { name, code, flag } = obj;
      return `
        <li
          class="item"
          data-name="${name}"
          data-code="${code}"
          data-flag="${flag}"
        >
          <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
          <div class="name">${name} (+${code})</div>
        </li>
      `;
    }).join('');
  }
  
  // Toggle the container on/off
  function handleButton() {
    container.classList.toggle('show');
  }
  
  // No data available list item
  function createNoDataHtml() {
    return '<li class="nodata">No data available</li>';
  }
  
  // When the input is changed filter the data
  // according to the current value, and then
  // create some list items using that filtered data
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value) {
      const filtered = filterData(data, value);
      if (filtered.length) {
        list.innerHTML = createListHtml(filtered);
      } else {
        list.innerHTML = createNoDataHtml();
      }
    } else {
      list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
    }
  }
  
  // Create some button HTML
  function createButtonHtml(code, flag) {
    return `
      <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
      <div class="code">+${code}</div>
    `;
  }
  
  // Updates the selected list by removing the `selected`
  // class from all items, and then adding one to the clicked
  // item
  function updateSelected(list, item) {
    const items = list.querySelectorAll('.item');
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected'));
    item.classList.add('selected');
  }
  
  // When an item is clicked, grab the relevant data
  // attributes, create the new button HTML, and then 
  // close the container
  function handleListClick(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest('li') || e.target;
    if (item.classList.contains('item')) {
      const { code, flag } = item.dataset;
      xbutton.innerHTML = createButtonHtml(code, flag);
      updateSelected(list, item);
      container.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
  
  list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
```

```css
  .country-code-selector .telcode {
       margin-bottom: 1em;
       display: flex;
  }
  .country-code-selector .telcode div.code, .item div.name {
       margin-left: 0.25em;
  }
  .country-code-selector .container {
       display: none;
       width: 350px;
       border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .country-code-selector .show {
       display: block;
  }
  .country-code-selector .list {
       height: 100px;
       list-style: none;
       margin: 1em 0 0 0;
       padding: 0;
       overflow-y: scroll;
       border: 1px soldi darkgray;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item {
       display: flex;
       padding: 0.25em;
       border: 1px solid lightgray;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item:hover, .item.selected {
       background-color: lightyellow;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="country-code-selector">
  <button type="button" class="telcode">Tel code</button>
  <section class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for country" />
    <ul class="list"></ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an onclick event to the body and remove it that way.

Comment: How? Please write a code for me

Comment: Try: document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (container.contains(event.target)) {
    if (container.classList.contains('show')) {
      container.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
});

Comment: I believe it should work

Comment: Not Working Sir